# Debugging java protobuf objects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

String data that's parsed into protobuf generated objects are stored in LiteralByteStrings. The problem I'm having is, when I inspect these objects in the debugger, Byte Strings aren't human readable. Is there any way to configure the debugger, or maybe a plugin, that would allow me to inspect these objects in a human readable fashion without manually converting them all to Strings via code?

Comment: What does this string object data look like? This is after you have encoded the protocol buffer object right?